# Difference between the following nodejs codes

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

## first code

```
net.createServer(function(socket){
    socket.on('data',function(id){
        getUserDetails(function(){console.log(id)});
    });
});

function getUserDetails(next){ 
    next();
}
```

## Second Code

```
net.createServer(function(socket){
    socket.on('data',function(id){
        getUserDetails(function(){console.log(id)});
    });
});

function getUserDetails(next){
    console.log(id); 
    next();
}
```

The first code logs id where as the second code gives error. I understand that getUserDetails has no access to id but how come the callback passed to getUserDetails has access to id?

Comment: `id` is not in scope in the second code. It is only in scope within the callback to `socket.on`

Comment: The variables a function has access to are based on where the function is *defined*, not where it is *called*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` is a variable scoped to the callback function of `socket.on('data')` event.

the `getUserDetails` method is not in that scope - therefore it can't access this variable.

The function you sent as a parameter to `getUserDetails` is declared inside the scope of the callback function where the `id` variable is in, so it can access it.